# Python Pandas add Filename Column CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob

My python code works correctly in the below example. My code combines a directory of CSV files and matches the headers. However, I want to take it a step further - how do I add a column that appends the filename of the CSV that was used?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

globbed_files = glob.glob("*.csv") #creates a list of all csv files

data = [] # pd.concat takes a list of dataframes as an agrument
for csv in globbed_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv)
    data.append(frame)

bigframe = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True) #dont want pandas to try an align row indexes
bigframe.to_csv("Pandas_output2.csv")
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This should work:

```
import os

for csv in globbed_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(csv)
    data.append(frame)
```

`frame['filename']` creates a new column named `filename` and `os.path.basename()` turns a path like `/a/d/c.txt` into the filename `c.txt`.

Comment: Awesome. I knew it was easy! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mike's answer above works perfectly. In case any googlers run into the following error:

```
>>> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<type 'str'>"; 
    only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

It's possibly because the separator is not correct. I was using a custom csv file so the separator was `^`. Becuase of that I needed to include the separator in the `pd.read_csv` call.

```
import os

for csv in globbed_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv, sep='^')
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(csv)
    data.append(frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

files variable contains all list of csv files in your present directory. Such as
`['FileName1.csv',FileName2.csv']`. You also need to remove `".csv"`. You can use `.split()` function. Below is simple logic. This will work for you.

```
files = glob.glob("*.csv") 
for i in files:
    
    df=pd.read_csv(i)
    df['New Column name'] = i.split(".")[0]
    df.to_csv(i.split(".")[0]+".csv")
```