# Read multiple csv and add column of date of csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple csv files in format 'name' + 'date', eg 'data 2020-07-01.csv'. I am able to read multiple csv files with glob as in:

```
all_files = glob.glob(path + "*.csv")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files], ignore_index = True)
```

But what I want to be able to do is add a column containing the date part of the file name string when doing the multi file read. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas add Filename Column CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857659/python-pandas-add-filename-column-csv)

Comment: Sorry late reply @MaxFeinberg. Yes it does. thanks